# Problem with time format on x-as not displaying correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I've made a 24 hour graphic (with different y-axes). So far so good.

But the x-axe is not displaying as I wanted.

1/ the time is not displayed correctly 05:59:00 instead of 06:00:00

2/ the x-axe should stop at 24:00:00 (now it goes further).

Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\def\removeleadingzeros#1{\if0#1 \expandafter\else#1\fi}

\def\transformtime#1:#2:#3!{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
%\pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60+#3}
\pgfmathparse{\removeleadingzeros#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+\removeleadingzeros#2*60+\removeleadingzeros#3}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}


\pgfplotsset{
timeplot zero/.initial=0,
timeplot/.style={
    x coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
    x coord inv trafo/.code={%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{##1-floor(##1/60)*60}
        \def\pgfmathresult{\pgfmathparse{mod(\hours,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\hours,60))}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{mod(\minutes,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\minutes,60))}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{mod(\seconds,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\seconds,60))}\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    },
scaled x ticks=false,
xticklabel=\tick
}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{boom.dat}
tijd diameter
00:00:00    656.405681
00:15:00    656.410403
00:30:00    656.415722
00:45:00    656.419879
01:00:00    656.422925
01:15:00    656.425762
01:30:00    656.429439
01:45:00    656.432858
02:00:00    656.435443
02:15:00    656.437564
02:30:00    656.438722
02:45:00    656.441318
03:00:00    656.443924
03:15:00    656.446608
03:30:00    656.449341
03:45:00    656.450762
04:00:00    656.451835
04:15:00    656.453
04:30:00    656.454701
04:45:00    656.456525
05:00:00    656.458294
05:15:00    656.460722
05:30:00    656.462619
05:45:00    656.464791
06:00:00    656.466648
06:15:00    656.467714
06:30:00    656.469632
06:45:00    656.470793
07:00:00    656.471614
07:15:00    656.47177
07:30:00    656.472144
07:45:00    656.472204
08:00:00    656.472353
08:15:00    656.471947
08:30:00    656.471044
08:45:00    656.467682
09:00:00    656.45527
09:15:00    656.438903
09:30:00    656.422273
09:45:00    656.41521
10:00:00    656.408804
10:15:00    656.402313
10:30:00    656.393826
10:45:00    656.385612
11:00:00    656.378146
11:15:00    656.372256
11:30:00    656.367282
11:45:00    656.361468
12:00:00    656.355557
12:15:00    656.350256
12:30:00    656.343752
12:45:00    656.337133
13:00:00    656.332531
13:15:00    656.32958
13:30:00    656.328682
13:45:00    656.327219
14:00:00    656.321448
14:15:00    656.315754
14:30:00    656.312755
14:45:00    656.311984
15:00:00    656.31289
15:15:00    656.313705
15:30:00    656.316576
15:45:00    656.323175
16:00:00    656.327068
16:15:00    656.326734
16:30:00    656.329307
16:45:00    656.34159
17:00:00    656.344922
17:15:00    656.344023
17:30:00    656.34417
17:45:00    656.344636
18:00:00    656.345115
18:15:00    656.344474
18:30:00    656.344168
18:45:00    656.34317
19:00:00    656.343425
19:15:00    656.343974
19:30:00    656.345429
19:45:00    656.351991
20:00:00    656.361141
20:15:00    656.366497
20:30:00    656.374289
20:45:00    656.381799
21:00:00    656.389487
21:15:00    656.395972
21:30:00    656.402692
21:45:00    656.408891
22:00:00    656.416834
22:15:00    656.422846
22:30:00    656.428715
22:45:00    656.435375
23:00:00    656.441634
23:15:00    656.445468
23:30:00    656.449594
23:45:00    656.452806
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}{sapstroom.dat}
tijd sapstroom
00:00:00    4.85408
00:15:00    4.57286
00:30:00    4.39551
00:45:00    4.4178
01:00:00    4.04949
01:15:00    3.77214
01:30:00    3.62084
01:45:00    3.46315
02:00:00    3.28671
02:15:00    3.21523
02:30:00    3.13485
02:45:00    2.97071
03:00:00    2.88493
03:15:00    2.96935
03:30:00    2.48116
03:45:00    2.45723
04:00:00    2.38146
04:15:00    2.37392
04:30:00    2.48235
04:45:00    2.28593
05:00:00    2.23122
05:15:00    2.20008
05:30:00    2.13761
05:45:00    2.05941
06:00:00    1.95399
06:15:00    1.90721
06:30:00    1.79834
06:45:00    1.77564
07:00:00    1.86757
07:15:00    2.13706
07:30:00    2.75334
07:45:00    3.49142
08:00:00    4.59272
08:15:00    6.20182
08:30:00    8.13804
08:45:00    10.2965
09:00:00    12.6352
09:15:00    14.649
09:30:00    16.9704
09:45:00    18.306
10:00:00    19.6905
10:15:00    20.6927
10:30:00    21.2783
10:45:00    21.9715
11:00:00    22.2801
11:15:00    22.4729
11:30:00    22.697
11:45:00    22.5211
12:00:00    22.9484
12:15:00    22.9198
12:30:00    22.9355
12:45:00    23.1047
13:00:00    23.0004
13:15:00    23.0681
13:30:00    22.7262
13:45:00    22.7039
14:00:00    23.0067
14:15:00    23.2884
14:30:00    23.2097
14:45:00    22.9358
15:00:00    22.478
15:15:00    21.9537
15:30:00    21.1719
15:45:00    21.2557
16:00:00    21.1705
16:15:00    22.4717
16:30:00    21.3172
16:45:00    19.8637
17:00:00    20.242
17:15:00    21.574
17:30:00    21.7862
17:45:00    21.4883
18:00:00    21.0291
18:15:00    20.684
18:30:00    20.9946
18:45:00    21.6095
19:00:00    21.0845
19:15:00    20.2188
19:30:00    19.1834
19:45:00    18.3425
20:00:00    17.5752
20:15:00    17.0377
20:30:00    15.6622
20:45:00    14.5367
21:00:00    13.3425
21:15:00    11.8389
21:30:00    10.4741
21:45:00    9.53448
22:00:00    8.7462
22:15:00    7.98585
22:30:00    7.51326
22:45:00    7.01831
23:00:00    6.48857
23:15:00    5.97139
23:30:00    5.63499
23:45:00    5.26984
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%axis lines=center,
    xmin=00:00:00, ymax=24:00:00,
    ymin=656.3, ymax=656.5,
    title=Boomdiagram,
    xlabel=Tijdstip,
    ylabel=Diameter (mm),
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0,
    xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00,12:00:00,18:00:00,24:00:00},
    %minor xtick={00:15:00,00:30:00,00:45:00,01:00:00,01:15:00,01:30:00,01:45:00},
    minor ytick={656.1,656.32,...,656.48},
    grid=both,
    width=\linewidth,
    %height=8cm,
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
tick label style={font=\small},
    x tick label style={rotate=-90},
            ]
\addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1] table [x=tijd, y=diameter] {boom.dat}; \label{plot_one}
\addlegendentry{Diameter}
\end{axis}



\begin{axis}[
%axis lines=center,
    xmin=00:00:00, ymax=24:00:00,
    ymin=0, ymax=25,
    title=Boomdiagram,
    xlabel=Tijdstip,
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel=Sapstroom,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0,
    xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00,12:00:00,18:00:00,24:00:00},
    grid=both,
    width=\linewidth,
    %height=8cm,
    x tick label style={rotate=-90},
tick label style={font=\small},
    ]
\addplot[red,mark=triangle*] table [x=tijd, y=sapstroom] {sapstroom.dat};\label{plot_two}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{Sapstroom}
\addlegendentry{Boomdiameter}

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a typo: `xmin=00:00:00, ymax=24:00:00,` should probably be `xmin=00:00:00, xmax=24:00:00,`. BTW, use "axis" instead of "axe" (or use an ice axe ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing the typos in `xmax` (which were typed as `ymax` twice) and a tiny bit of cheating (I changed the xticks to `xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00.5,12:00:00,18:00:00.5,24:00:00}`, i.e. increased 6am and 6pm by 0.5 seconds; I guess there is a rounding issue somewhere) I arrive at

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\def\removeleadingzeros#1{\if0#1 \expandafter\else#1\fi}

\def\transformtime#1:#2:#3!{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
%\pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60+#3}
\pgfmathparse{\removeleadingzeros#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+\removeleadingzeros#2*60+\removeleadingzeros#3}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}


\pgfplotsset{
timeplot zero/.initial=0,
timeplot/.style={
    x coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
    x coord inv trafo/.code={%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{##1-floor(##1/60)*60}
        \def\pgfmathresult{\pgfmathparse{mod(\hours,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\hours,60))}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{mod(\minutes,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\minutes,60))}\pgfmathresult:\pgfmathparse{mod(\seconds,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\seconds,60))}\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    },
scaled x ticks=false,
xticklabel=\tick
}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{boom.dat}
tijd diameter
00:00:00    656.405681
00:15:00    656.410403
00:30:00    656.415722
00:45:00    656.419879
01:00:00    656.422925
01:15:00    656.425762
01:30:00    656.429439
01:45:00    656.432858
02:00:00    656.435443
02:15:00    656.437564
02:30:00    656.438722
02:45:00    656.441318
03:00:00    656.443924
03:15:00    656.446608
03:30:00    656.449341
03:45:00    656.450762
04:00:00    656.451835
04:15:00    656.453
04:30:00    656.454701
04:45:00    656.456525
05:00:00    656.458294
05:15:00    656.460722
05:30:00    656.462619
05:45:00    656.464791
06:00:00    656.466648
06:15:00    656.467714
06:30:00    656.469632
06:45:00    656.470793
07:00:00    656.471614
07:15:00    656.47177
07:30:00    656.472144
07:45:00    656.472204
08:00:00    656.472353
08:15:00    656.471947
08:30:00    656.471044
08:45:00    656.467682
09:00:00    656.45527
09:15:00    656.438903
09:30:00    656.422273
09:45:00    656.41521
10:00:00    656.408804
10:15:00    656.402313
10:30:00    656.393826
10:45:00    656.385612
11:00:00    656.378146
11:15:00    656.372256
11:30:00    656.367282
11:45:00    656.361468
12:00:00    656.355557
12:15:00    656.350256
12:30:00    656.343752
12:45:00    656.337133
13:00:00    656.332531
13:15:00    656.32958
13:30:00    656.328682
13:45:00    656.327219
14:00:00    656.321448
14:15:00    656.315754
14:30:00    656.312755
14:45:00    656.311984
15:00:00    656.31289
15:15:00    656.313705
15:30:00    656.316576
15:45:00    656.323175
16:00:00    656.327068
16:15:00    656.326734
16:30:00    656.329307
16:45:00    656.34159
17:00:00    656.344922
17:15:00    656.344023
17:30:00    656.34417
17:45:00    656.344636
18:00:00    656.345115
18:15:00    656.344474
18:30:00    656.344168
18:45:00    656.34317
19:00:00    656.343425
19:15:00    656.343974
19:30:00    656.345429
19:45:00    656.351991
20:00:00    656.361141
20:15:00    656.366497
20:30:00    656.374289
20:45:00    656.381799
21:00:00    656.389487
21:15:00    656.395972
21:30:00    656.402692
21:45:00    656.408891
22:00:00    656.416834
22:15:00    656.422846
22:30:00    656.428715
22:45:00    656.435375
23:00:00    656.441634
23:15:00    656.445468
23:30:00    656.449594
23:45:00    656.452806
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}{sapstroom.dat}
tijd sapstroom
00:00:00    4.85408
00:15:00    4.57286
00:30:00    4.39551
00:45:00    4.4178
01:00:00    4.04949
01:15:00    3.77214
01:30:00    3.62084
01:45:00    3.46315
02:00:00    3.28671
02:15:00    3.21523
02:30:00    3.13485
02:45:00    2.97071
03:00:00    2.88493
03:15:00    2.96935
03:30:00    2.48116
03:45:00    2.45723
04:00:00    2.38146
04:15:00    2.37392
04:30:00    2.48235
04:45:00    2.28593
05:00:00    2.23122
05:15:00    2.20008
05:30:00    2.13761
05:45:00    2.05941
06:00:00    1.95399
06:15:00    1.90721
06:30:00    1.79834
06:45:00    1.77564
07:00:00    1.86757
07:15:00    2.13706
07:30:00    2.75334
07:45:00    3.49142
08:00:00    4.59272
08:15:00    6.20182
08:30:00    8.13804
08:45:00    10.2965
09:00:00    12.6352
09:15:00    14.649
09:30:00    16.9704
09:45:00    18.306
10:00:00    19.6905
10:15:00    20.6927
10:30:00    21.2783
10:45:00    21.9715
11:00:00    22.2801
11:15:00    22.4729
11:30:00    22.697
11:45:00    22.5211
12:00:00    22.9484
12:15:00    22.9198
12:30:00    22.9355
12:45:00    23.1047
13:00:00    23.0004
13:15:00    23.0681
13:30:00    22.7262
13:45:00    22.7039
14:00:00    23.0067
14:15:00    23.2884
14:30:00    23.2097
14:45:00    22.9358
15:00:00    22.478
15:15:00    21.9537
15:30:00    21.1719
15:45:00    21.2557
16:00:00    21.1705
16:15:00    22.4717
16:30:00    21.3172
16:45:00    19.8637
17:00:00    20.242
17:15:00    21.574
17:30:00    21.7862
17:45:00    21.4883
18:00:00    21.0291
18:15:00    20.684
18:30:00    20.9946
18:45:00    21.6095
19:00:00    21.0845
19:15:00    20.2188
19:30:00    19.1834
19:45:00    18.3425
20:00:00    17.5752
20:15:00    17.0377
20:30:00    15.6622
20:45:00    14.5367
21:00:00    13.3425
21:15:00    11.8389
21:30:00    10.4741
21:45:00    9.53448
22:00:00    8.7462
22:15:00    7.98585
22:30:00    7.51326
22:45:00    7.01831
23:00:00    6.48857
23:15:00    5.97139
23:30:00    5.63499
23:45:00    5.26984
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%axis lines=center,
    xmin=00:00:00, xmax=24:00:00,
    ymin=656.3, ymax=656.5,
    title=Boomdiagram,
    xlabel=Tijdstip,
    ylabel=Diameter (mm),
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0,
    xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00.5,12:00:00,18:00:00.5,24:00:00},
    %minor xtick={00:15:00,00:30:00,00:45:00,01:00:00,01:15:00,01:30:00,01:45:00},
    minor ytick={656.1,656.32,...,656.48},
    grid=both,
    width=\linewidth,
    %height=8cm,
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
tick label style={font=\small},
    x tick label style={rotate=-90},
            ]
\addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1] table [x=tijd, y=diameter] {boom.dat}; \label{plot_one}
\addlegendentry{Diameter}
\end{axis}



\begin{axis}[
%axis lines=center,
    xmin=00:00:00, xmax=24:00:00,
    ymin=0, ymax=25,
    title=Boomdiagram,
    xlabel=Tijdstip,
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel=Sapstroom,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0,
    xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00.5,12:00:00,18:00:00.5,24:00:00},
    grid=both,
    width=\linewidth,
    %height=8cm,
    x tick label style={rotate=-90},
tick label style={font=\small},
    ]
\addplot[red,mark=triangle*] table [x=tijd, y=sapstroom] {sapstroom.dat};\label{plot_two}
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{Sapstroom}
\addlegendentry{Boomdiameter}

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why on earth do I have fat finger syndrome (xmax vs ymax), thanx

Comment: @ArneTimperman It is certainly not easier when you are born with claws. ;-)

Comment: I've copied your code, because I couldn't find what you had changed, besides the x and y

Comment: @ArneTimperman Oh, I should have said explicitly: I changed the `xticks` to `xtick={00:00:00,06:00:00.5,12:00:00,18:00:00.5,24:00:00},`, i.e. increased 6am and 6pm by 0.5 seconds. I guess there is a rounding issue somewhere.